# Affiliation when I have already resigned and am currently unemployed

Tags: paper-submission, affiliation

What should I use as author address for my paper when I have already resigned from my job and am currently unemployed? Also, my previous supervisor and I did not part in good terms, so I am hesitant to use my previous employer as address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would still use the affiliation of the institution which paid you during the time you worked on this paper. If however, the majority of the work was done after you resigned, I see no problem in using "Independent Researcher" or "Freelance".

I faced this problem when switching institutions. Typically papers published during the transition were written by the old institution and paid for by the new. I use the new affiliation as my first and include the old as the second affiliation.

Comment: I've also seen footnotes on the affiliation reading "Portions of this work were undertaken at < _different institute_ >" if you want to acknowledge the place without claiming the affiliation currently.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was very useful. I think I have an idea now on how to address this.